# How do I create a custom map with subtle details for a localized place?

Tags: google-maps, android

I've worked with google maps for android previously.

But, now I need to build **custom maps for a place such as a home**, showing bedrooms, kitchen and living room, **or a factory**, displaying all the departments. I would like to use these maps in an android application. How do I achieve this objective?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make choice if you want to use vector features or tiled layer:

1) for vector features, you can use google maps api v3 and create the rooms as polygons, circles, line features... in general, to use [overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays) - see [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays).

2) for tiled layers, you have to place the tiles (usualy png) on your server, create your own ImageMapType object and use it as a standard layer or overlay layer:

```
    var mapTypeOpts = {
            getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {
                    var b = zoom;
                    var a = coord;
                    return "http://www.myserver.org/tiles" +
                        zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            isPng: true,
            alt: 'My Layer - basic map',
            name: 'My Layer',
            minZoom: 15,
            maxZoom: 20
    };

    // now there are two ways how to set this up
    // 1st way - as a full layer, switchable instead of e.g. google satellite map:
    this.map.setOptions({ mapTypeControlOptions: {
                            mapTypeIds: [
                                    google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                                    google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
                                    google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
                                    google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                                    'My Layer'
                            ]
                         }});
    map.mapTypes.set('My Layer', new google.maps.ImageMapType(mapTypeOpts));

    // 2nd way - use it as an overlay layer, used TOGETHER with normal google layers:
    map.overlayMapTypes.push(new google.maps.ImageMapType(mapTypeOpts));
```

For adding custom logos and copyrights to layers [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312439/684229).